# How to show the result of a subreport only when a column value in the master report changes

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I want to show the result of a subreport only when a column value in the master report changes

[image: look at the Name column]

In the picture above first two rows have same values (Test) for "Name" column.
in the third row "Name" column have FEDEX value so Name column value changing
here I want to show subreport result. similarly when "Name" column value changes from *FEDEX* to *UPS* again subreport result should be shown.

Comment: Where the supreport is placed?

Comment: Sounds like a `GROUP` on `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

In the report designer, you can add a group. The group by expression should be the `$F{Name}` field. Then, if needed, you can add a group header and / or a group footer.

Everything should be in place with this. Also, you should check the comment from AlexK on your other question: *Did you read about [Data Grouping](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups)?*